# proving $ (A \rightarrow B \vee C )\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B) \vee (A\rightarrow C))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I'm looking for a way to prow
$ (A \rightarrow B \vee C )\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B) \vee (A\rightarrow C))$
from the following axioms and rules
$$\vdash A \rightarrow A$$
$$\vdash A \wedge B \rightarrow A$$
$$\vdash A \wedge B \rightarrow B$$
$$\vdash A \rightarrow A \vee B $$
$$\vdash B \rightarrow A \vee B $$
$$A, B \vdash A\wedge B$$
$$A, A \rightarrow B \vdash B$$
$$\vdash A\wedge (B \vee C) \rightarrow (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$$
$$\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow B)$$
$$\vdash (A\rightarrow B)\wedge (A\rightarrow C) \rightarrow(A\rightarrow B\wedge C)$$
$$\vdash (A\rightarrow C)\wedge (B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow(A\vee B \rightarrow C)$$
$$\vdash (A\rightarrow B)\wedge (B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$$
$$(A\rightarrow B) \vee E,(C\rightarrow D) \vee E \vdash((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow D)) \vee E$$ 
$$A \vee C, (A\rightarrow B)\vee C\vdash B\vee C$$
$$A\rightarrow B, C\rightarrow D\vdash(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow D)$$

Comment: This axiom set is not independent.  ⊢[A→(B→B)] and A,(A→B)⊢B yields ⊢A→A.

Comment: Where does this axiom set come from?  What logical systems is it related to, and how is it related?  What theorems do you have so far?

Comment: I don't undrestand. please tell me why that axioms is not independent. thank's a lot.

Comment: this axioms and rules are logic for subintuitionistic logic (SJ).

Comment: If we have [A→(B→B)], then we can substitute any theorem for "A" and then detach (B→B).  For example, substituting "A" with [A→(B→B)] in [A→(B→B)] we obtain [[A→(B→B)]→(B→B)].  Then, since ⊢[A→(B→B)] and we have A,(A→B)⊢B ([A→(B→B)] has form "A", and [[A→(B→B)]→(B→B)] has form "(A→B)"), we can infer ⊢(B→B).  Then we can substitute "B" with "A" in (B→B) and we obtain ⊢(A→A).  Thus, if  ⊢[A→(B→B)] and {A,(A→B)}⊢B, then ⊢(A→A).

Comment: Thank you very much for answer question. you think that (A→B∨C)→((A→B)∨(A→C)) proved from that axioms. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have the Deduction Theorem?  Can both members of {[A→(B→A)], [(A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))]} get proved?  I've found Greg Restall's paper which mentions SJ, I haven't read it though: http://consequently.org/papers/subint.pdf

Comment: We do not have Deduction theorem.

Comment: Can you help me? I can't prove (A→B∨C)→((A→B)∨(A→C)) from That Axioms and rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See :

- Greg Restall, [Subintuitionistic logic](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1040609299), *NDJFL*, 35-1 (1994).

The system is a subsystem of [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

If so, the formula :

> $(A→B∨C)→((A→B)∨(A→C))$

is not provable, because it is not *intuitionistically valid*.

---

For a counterexample to the formula, consider the Kripke model with three nodes : $w_0, v_1, v_2$, where $w_0$ is the root (the *base* world) and $w_0Rv_1, w_0Rv_2$, such that :

> $w_0$ *forces* no propositional variable, while : $v_1 \vDash A,B$ and $v_2 \vDash A,C$.

The semantical rules for $\lor$ and $\rightarrow$ are the same used for intuitionistic logic : see **Definition 2.1**, page 118.

Comment: How do you prove that [(A→(B∨C))→((A→B)∨(A→C))] is not intuitionistically valid?